# Cython ImportError: No module named parallel

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, enthought

I am trying to access the new parallel features of Cython 0.15 (using
Cython 0.15.1). However, if I try this minimal example (testp.py), taken from http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/parallelism.html:

```
from cython.parallel import prange, parallel, threadid
cdef int i
cdef int sum = 0

for i in prange(n, nogil=True):
    sum += i
print sum
```

with this setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
import numpy

ext = Extension("testp", ["testp.pyx"], include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()],
                extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'], extra_link_args ['-fopenmp'])
setup(ext_modules=[ext], cmdclass={'build_ext': build_ext})
```

when I `import testp`, Python tells me: `ImportError: No module named
parallel`. And in fact, if I browse the Cython package in the
site-packages, I cannot find any file or directory that is called
`parallel`. But I thought it should be included somewhere in the
release? Could someone please clarify for a confused user?

Comment: OK, so the solution was that I still had the wrong version installed. "python setup.py install" didn't upgrade my Cython version. But with the help of "easy_install --upgrade Cython", everything worked fine! Thanks people, problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check all of your python modules in python command-line using:

```
>>> help('modules')
```

And then try to install/reinstall cython using easy_install or pip.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know easy_install! With it, upgrading to 0.15.1 was - well - easy! Thank you for the recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Cython 0.15+

cython.parallel exists in Shadow.py:

```
import sys
sys.modules['cython.parallel'] = CythonDotParallel()
```

And the `Shadow.py` can be located in your Python's dist-packages directory like `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/` in Linux

Comment: Maybe I really installed into the wrong directory, because the only Shadow.py that I find is located in site-packages/Cython, and it is not containing any "parallel". Strange, I used the normal "python setup.py install" method.